# convert command to bash script for linux

Tags: linux, bash, command

Hej,

I have a command script and i need it to make it automatic for Linux.
i have the following command and it must be install de path/update automatic.
so it must be a bash script, we have Linux machine's and i path/update it manual but it must go automatic and that's why i need a bash script.
maybe somebody can help if you need more info i will send it
thank you

```
sudo apt-get update;   
sudo apt-get install gcc;
sudo apt-get install autoconf;
sudo apt-get install libtool;
sudo apt-get install pkg-config;
sudo apt-get install libselinux1-dev;
sudo apt-get install liblockdev1-dev;
sudo apt-get install gawk;
sudo apt-get install g++;
sudo apt-get install c++;
sudo apt-get install libgudev-1.0-dev;
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev;

mkdir -p $HOME/distr/libcec; 
wget -P $HOME/distr/libcec https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec/archive/master.zip;
unzip $HOME/distr/libcec/master.zip -d $HOME/distr/libcec/;

cd $HOME/distr/libcec/libcec-master;
./bootstrap;

./configure --with-rpi-include-path=/opt/vc/include --with-rpi-lib-path=/opt/vc/lib --enable-rpi;
make;
sudo make install;

sudo apt-get install cec-utils;
```

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried? You can add a list of packages to the `apt-get` command: `sudo apt-get install gcc autoconf libtool ...`.

Comment: What's the question here? Also you do realize that `apt-get install` can take more than one package as argument, right? So you don't need N calls to `apt-get` to install N packages you can do it with just one.

Comment: The Q is. i use putty to command the above used command and now my boss says we have Linux machine's, the previous installation i have do it manuel by typing, my boss whant that if we go to the Linux machine we run the bash script and that it installs automatic all the packages. sorry for bad english

Comment: i need a bash file that do the everthing automatic and  install the packages in the Linux machine's without typing only click on it and let it do automatic!

Comment: i don't scripting at all what you all say is new to me, i am busy for 3/4 hours and i only have a headache and no info else i don't understand advanced bash scipting, i don't understand even simple bash scripting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not understand scripting or cannot accomplish the task your boss has given you then you should tell him to get someone else to do it.  That said, scripting as its simplest is a file made executable that contain the same commands one would type at the terminal.  There are plenty of tutorials on the Internet to give you guidance however I'll at least give you the bare minimum basics.

Create a file and make the first line: `#!/bin/bash`   This is assuming that is the actual location of `bash` on the system, if not then adjust the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line appropriately.

In a terminal type `man apt-get` to read up on how to properly use `apt-get`.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install package1 package2 package3 etc...
# Other needed commands go below.
```

Once saved then make it executable, in a terminal: `chmod +x file`

This is at its most basic however there are additional options that can be added to the `apt-get` command if necessary as well as adding error handling to the script.  BTW You do not need to be placing a semi-colon `;` at the end of each line in a `bash` script, it's just not necessary.

Comment: i have already don it, it works good and installing automatic, you are a little late but thanks anyway, i am for school on this job i only need work for 2 months thats wy i must do task thats why i asked.

but thanks anyway